# UsbIP client for Windows without needing to put the whole system in "Test mode"?

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, windows-subsystem-for-linux, remote-control

I'm trying to connect some devices I've got in another room to my computer so it recognizes them as if they were connected through the USB. The setup I'm using is with a Raspberry Pi 4 (Model B):

```
laser engraver ---- USB port 1 
                              + --- Raspberry w/ usbip server --- (WiFi) ---- Windows 11 PC
        webcam ---- USB port 2
```

I've tried [this client](https://github.com/vadimgrn/usbip-win2) but it needs the Windows system to be set to "Test signed" mode, which requires to change bootable settings as I cannot modify it (Safe Boot mode is currently enabled). *Furthermore, when I install it, all my USB ports stop working.*

Apart from that, putting Windows into "Test signed" mode adds a watermark in the desktop (quite annoying) and it also allows any app to do as they wish, since you're not enabling this in a per-app basis, but for the whole system, which seems a security issue.

**Is there any reliable, free option to enable USP-IP in Windows 11 without having to put my PC's security at risk?**

Or could it be possible to run WSL, **install the client in the WSL and share the USB devices** to my main Windows 11 installation so that I can recognize and use them from Windows apps?

Comment: If it's really important.  You could get yourself a code signing certificate yourself, build the driver yourself, to avoid having to put Windows in Test Signing mode.  Likewise, that particular project only supports Windows, it simply supports Linux USB/IP server.  So in order for Windows to communicate with the devices, even if you communicated with the server running within WSL, you would still need the driver. There is no free solution to the code signing certificate.

Comment: You could perhaps enable USP-IP via WSL2. The procedure is [here](https://www.geekbits.io/how-to-connect-a-usb-device-to-wsl-instance/). If it works for you I can put up an answer.

Comment: As @Ramhound says, I still need the driver to run it in Windows, so it seems there's no free solution for this. That's a shame. I've seen VirtualHere which (at least the trial) works nicely, although is far from free.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this task without needing to put the system in "Test Mode" in a very short time. Please be aware that I'm not a Windows user though, so I'm not really familiar with specifics.

My Test Setup was this:

**Server**: Raspberry Pi 4B with a Canon Camera connected to USB3

**Client**: Windows 10

I used software from this repository:
https://github.com/cezanne/usbip-win

Since the README can seem a bit intimidating and the compiled program may not be easy to find here is a **quick summary** of what I did:

- Downloaded [usbip-win 0.3.6-dev](https://github.com/cezanne/usbip-win/releases/download/v0.3.6-dev/usbip-win-0.3.6-dev.zip) from the [releases page](https://github.com/cezanne/usbip-win/releases)
- Extracted Archive
- In CMD: usbip.exe install
- In the Defender Warning Dialoge: More Information -> Install anyway
- In CMD: usbip.exe attach -r  -b 2-2

Worked like a charm straight away.